# How do you upload files in Parse using CURL?

Tags: php, parsing, curl

I have the following:

curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appid" 
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: restkey" 
-H "Content-Type: text/plain" 
-d 'Hello, World!' 
 https://api.parse.com/1/files/hello.txt

And I get back:

{"url":"http://files.parse.com/7680c0e7-b398-4b43-91f0-61b12934c690/08d828ef-1185-4036-b8ab-228764fbeb69-hello.txt","name":"08d828ef-1185-4036-b8ab-228764fbeb69-hello.txt"}

What's the file name I should use?

Answer (score 0):

the URL returned - you take everything after http://files.parse.com/

That comes to the following:

curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appid" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: reskey" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
   "name": "blisdco",
    "picture": {
     "name": "7680c0e7-b398-4b43-91f0-61b12934c690/08d828ef-1185-4036-b8ab-228764fbeb69-hello.txt",
      "__type": "File"
    }
   }' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/CustomerImages

And what is returned is:

{"createdAt":"2012-06-12T20:16:05.360Z","objectId":"yHLhqMgBAj"}

If you look at CustomerImages table in the Parse Data Browser, you'll see the entry - including the file name portion of the URL.